# PHP: get PID of a specific process

Tags: php, linux, nohup

I have a QNAP box, that runs a flavor of linux and I am having problems getting the PID of a process using a php script. What I have so far:

```
$command = "PATH=$PATH:/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/bin: nohup /opt/bin/plowdown -o /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/plowshare http://www.megaupload.com/?d=m7duotr1 2> /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/plowshare/outputeeds.txt > /dev/null &";
exec($command, $out);
$result = $out[0];
echo $result;
```

If I run the command through PUTTY, I get:

```
[~] # nohup /opt/bin/plowdown -o /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/plowshare http://www.megaupload.com/?d=m7duotr1 2> /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/plowshare/outputteeds.txt > /dev/null &
22526
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Cristian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell does not normally print the PID of a process it starts in background, unless it's interactive. Otherwise, you would get tons of output during bootup just from the PIDs of all the processes that get started.

So you need to make the shell print the PID. Do

```
 exec("(PATH=$PATH:/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/bin: " . 
      "nohup /opt/bin/plowdown -o /share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/plowshare " .
      "http://www.megaupload.com/?d=m7duotr1 2> " . 
      "/share/MD0_DATA/Qdownload/plowshare/outputeeds.txt > /dev/null &);" . 
      "echo $$;", $out);
```

Comment: any idea why the code from here is not working properly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133570/php-foreach-problem-with-a-script is an extent of the code you helped me with a while back.

Answer (score 1):

http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that as well but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: What's the problem specifically with calling a function wihtout parameters? How many different ways of using it do you have?

Comment: As a follow-up: the OP doesn't want the PID of the PHP process, but the PID of the process that exec starts in the background.

Comment: @Martin, not sure what you mean, but I need to have the PID of the plowdown process so I can store it and use it later on.

Comment: @Martin, I thought that is implied from my post ?!?

Comment: @Chris19: you subject says "get process pid", where everybody would guess this means "how to get your own process pid". The message then says "having problems getting the PID of a process", which still suggests that you want the PID of the current process. Strictly speaking, you are asking for the PID of any process, to which a quibbling answer would be "1" (this is always a valid PID).

Comment: In my mind it made sense, sorry, I'll change the title. Cheers.